# eclipse why some codes in java files have background color before the file is edited

Tags: eclipse

As shown in the following picture, some java files have background color for code, and once edit the file, the color disappears. I would like to cancel this behavior.

[image: background color]

Comment: That may be the code coverage data from running the code in 'coverage' mode using the EclEmma component of Eclipse - see [here](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.eclemma.doc%2Fpages%2Fannotations.html&cp%3D22_0_2)

Comment: @greg-449 >.< true. I just accidentally pressed ctrl-shift-f11, while I want to press f10 instead. And I noticed the diamond icon at the head of line. Do you know how to dehighlight (not disable highlight) it?

Comment: Sorry I don't use this. The link contains the full manual for EclEmma so it should be there.

Comment: @greg-449 **If you remove the coverage session, also the coverage coloring will disappear** yes, it says right there...